# Is there an example of a non context-sensitive language?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, grammars

I know $CSL\subset UL$ can be demonstrated by reduction to the absurd, but I've been trying to find a language that is in **Type 0** ($UL$) and not in **Context-Sensitive Languages** ($CSL$).

Is there any language with such restrictions that isn't a **Context-Sensitive** language?

Comment: As UL is the same as recursively enumerable and CSL the same as NSPACE[n] (see, e.g., [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)), you may use your favorite version of the [Space hierarchy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem) to get your language in UL \ CSL.

Comment: @Michaël Cadilhac, I think you can post it as answer so the question becomes answered.

Comment: @Kaveh You're right. @Michaël, post it as an answer, and add something if you want, to mark is at the right answer ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type 0 grammars denote exactly recursively enumerable languages, and CSL = NSPACE[$n$] (e.g., [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)).  Thus, your favorite proof of the [Space Hierarchy Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem) gives an explicit language in, say, NSPACE[$n^2$] \ NSPACE[$n$], thus in UL \ CSL.

Comment: Or more simply, any RE-complete problem, like the halting language.

Comment: Of course ; that's indeed the "farthest" language from CSL to fit, and I proposed the "farthest" language from UL for the same job.

Comment: to be more adequate with the statement "NSPACE[n2] \ NSPACE[n], thus in UL \ CSL", better to say it is so if P<>NP.

Answer (score 3):

Since deciding membership for a context-sensitive grammar is in $PSPACE$ ($NSPACE[n]$ even), any language not in $PSPACE$ is not expressable by a context-sensitive grammar. An example is therefore the language of all true propositions in Presburger arithmetic (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic).

Since we suspect that $PSPACE \neq EXPTIME$, we expect any $EXPTIME$-hard language to be sufficient. Alternatively, any $EXPSPACE$-hard problem is provably not context-sensitive by the space hierarchy theorem.